# Двоичные файлы в Java

Tags: java

Привет, профессионалы!
Никто не подскажет, как читать и записывать в двоичные файлы в Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public final class Sample {
    static
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(".", "sample");

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];

            is.read(data);
            os.write(data);

            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Использовать тут is.available - не лучшая идея, но для демонстрации - годится.